# What is the typical current draw of a battery powered smoke detector?

Tags: battery-operated, smoke-sensor

Often the battery operated smoke detectors take 9V batteries.

I want to replace batteries less often. Question [Why do smoke detectors run off 9v batteries?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156886/why-do-smoke-detectors-run-off-9v-batteries) doesn't offer a clue.

Should I look for capacity, and at which current draw?

Or should I look for another specification to choose a replacement battery for a smoke detector?

Answer (score 2):

## Shelf life

A battery operated **ionisation** smoke alarm typically draws less than 0.1 mW.

The background power requirement for **photoelectric** smoke alarms is similar to ionisation smoke alarms (typically around 0.2 mW).

With a current draw of typically **10 μA** to **20 μA**, the life of a 9V cell with a capacity of several hundred mAh will probably be limited by the battery shelf life rather than the energy capacity of the battery.

source: https://www.energyrating.gov.au/sites/default/files/documents/sb200405-smokealarms_0.pdf#page9

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a mains-powered smoke detector so it won’t draw any current from the battery, besides diode leakage (typically).
2. Use a long life lithium 9V battery.

This combination will easily last the life of the smoke detector - 10 years. Since consumer smoke detectors have to be replaced every 10 years, you’ve got 0 battery replacements and you can’t do any better than that :)

If the alarm is activated rarely, then you can just buy “10 year” detectors that have a built-in primary lithium cell rated to last at least 10 years. No mains power needed. Then you won’t even have to buy the battery separately.

**If your smoke detector is over 10 years old, you have to replace it!**

Comment: And in at least some places ( I don't know if this is based on federal or state laws or something else) you can't even buy "replace battery yourself" smoke detectors any more - they are all "10 year" smoke detectors.